# setting ACL in oracle cloud - APEX error ORA-24247 when creating a web source

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, acl

I'm new in oracle Cloud / Apex 19.1.... and I need help :-)

1. I try to crate a connection to a API web source :
   https://api.zelty.fr/2.1/ using a shared new web source.
2. using APEX I have an error ORA-24247, due to ACL.
3. I read a lot, and saw that i needed to create a ACL using script
   commands... but I don't see where I should post it ?
4. In APEX , using SQL , it doesn't work ! In Cloud console, there is a
       menu " create an ACL" but it doesn't work ...

Can you help me ?? 
Where should I send the commands ? which one ? 
Thanks very much in advance

Upgrade :
I tried to launch the following script in APEX / script SQL :

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
   acl => 'https://api.zelty.fr', 
   description => 'zelty',
    principal => 'LPDS',
    is_grant => TRUE,
    privilege => 'connect',
    start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    end_date => NULL);

  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
    acl => 'https://api.zelty.fr', 
    host => '*',
    lower_port => 1,
    upper_port => 9999); 

  COMMIT;
END;
```

but the error was :

```
ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 3 : PLS-00201: l'identificateur 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' doit être déclaré ORA-06512: à "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", ligne 592 ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 3 : PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06550: Ligne 11, colonne 3 : PLS-00201: l'identificateur 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' doit être déclaré ORA-06550: Ligne 11, colonne 3 : PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", ligne 1658 ORA-06512: à "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", ligne 578 ORA-06512: à "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", ligne 2033
```

Comment: you need a ACL rule to allow OUTBOUND traffic from the database - so you are trying to get to data outside of the DB in your APEX app via HTTP?

Comment: you can run the ACL rule code anywhere you can run SQL, but you'l need the proper oracle privs (fairly high level) to do this

Comment: Thank you , I tried to send this ...to the SQL script editor :BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
   acl => 'https://api.zelty.fr', 
   description => 'zelty',
    principal => 'LPDS',
    is_grant => TRUE,
    privilege => 'connect',
    start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    end_date => NULL);
  
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
    acl => 'https://api.zelty.fr', 
    host => '*',
    lower_port => 1,
    upper_port => 9999); 
  
  COMMIT;
END;

Comment: And it replied an error : ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 3 : PLS-00201: l'identificateur 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' doit être déclaré ORA-06512: à "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", ligne 592 ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 3 : PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06550: Ligne 11, colonne 3 : PLS-00201: l'identificateur 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' doit être déclaré ORA-06550: Ligne 11, colonne 3 : PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", ligne 1658 ORA-06512: à "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", ligne 578 ORA-06512: à "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", ligne 2033

Comment: Christophe, please update your question with the code and error - it's impossible to read in the comments

Comment: Thank you again for your prompt response ... I put it in the main post ... is it visible ?

Comment: PLS-00201 is the error you get when you do not have privileges to use the package `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN`. Enabling ACLs usually must be done with the **sys as sysdba** user.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm the owner , and Admin of this cloud database. Do you know how I can connect as the sys as sysdba ?

Answer (score 0):

For https u must use certificates.
look at link for example https://davidkyanek.blogspot.com/2017/04/using-oracle-wallets-to-connect-ssl.html